# Conditional Column Join in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to left join `Table b` onto `Table a` based on whether there's a match or not in SQLite. At first, try to join by their `type` but if there's no matching `type` then try to match by the first three character of `variant` with the `sku`.

```
Table a
+-------+---------+
| type  | variant |
+-------+---------+
| hat   | 10051   |
+-------+---------+
| cap   | 10062   |
+-------+---------+
| shirt | 10151   |
+-------+---------+
```

```
Table b
+-------+-----+-------+
| type  | sku | price |
+-------+-----+-------+
| cap   | 100 | 10    |
+-------+-----+-------+
| shirt | 200 | 20    |
+-------+-----+-------+
```

```
Output
+-------+---------+-------+
| type  | variant | price |
+-------+---------+-------+
| hat   | 10051   | 10    |
+-------+---------+-------+
| cap   | 10062   | 10    |
+-------+---------+-------+
| shirt | 20051   | 20    |
+-------+---------+-------+
```

Cheers!

Comment: Well the only thing that you can `JOIN` on is the `type` since that's the only thing in both `Table a` and `Table b`. However, you don't have a `hat` in `Table b`, so you can't get the output you show. Where is the price for `hat` coming from?

BTW: What have you tried so far? A `LEFT JOIN` would be correct if you want all the records from `Table a`.

Comment: @daShier In the case of `hat`, since the first three character of `variant` is `100` which matches with the `sku` of `cap` in Table b, then the price will be taken from `cap`

Comment: @sasawatc  First of all, the order that you mention the tables matters since that is critical to the meaning of a "left" join.  Your question said "left join Table b onto Table a".  Here `table b` is on the left.  Just as daShier points out, this would take all the rows from `Table b` and *only return rows from `Table a` when they match.*  The point is that your explanation contradicts your desired results.  You instead need a left join of `Table a` onto `Table b` (see the order of the tables is switched).

Comment: @sasawatc  The second critical concept is that not all join conditions can be obtained in one query.  It is often necessary to use sub-queries (i.e. nested queries or common-table expressions) to perform an initial query and then use those results in another query (or even sequence of nested queries or unioned queries) to get the desired results.

Comment: @CPerkins I could be wrong, but I believe that joining `[table b]` twice (as I did in my answer below), would be more efficient than using a sub-query. But perhaps the use of `ISNULL()` negates that. I don't know.

Comment: @daShier  Agreed.  I could have adjusted my statement to include something like "or multiple joins", but my intention was to emphasize that often the solution cannot be obtained by a select of a simple join.  I consider your answer a rather "advanced" solution since it has multiple joins on the same table using complex ON clause.  That isn't your vanilla select statement. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see lots of potential issues with the database design. I see a high probability that you will have pricing conflicts where two `variants` have the same `sku` but different `prices`. But, regardless, if that's what you have to work with then here's the query I would use:

```
    SELECT a.type, a.variant, IFNULL(v.price,b.price) as price
        FROM [table a] a 
        LEFT JOIN [table b] v on a.type = v.type
        LEFT JOIN [table b] b ON a.variant/100 = b.sku
    ORDER BY a.variant
```

Results:

```
type    variant price
hat     10051   10
cap     10062   10
shirt   10151   20
```

The trick here is to `JOIN [table b]` twice, once for matching the `type` and the second time for matching on the first three digits of the `variant` to the `sku`. Then, in the `SELECT` if the `variant.price` is not found (ie `NULL`) then use the matching of the `variant/sku`.

Note that I *assumed* that your `variant` and `sku` columns are of type `int`. If they are character types, then you will need to match the left most characters. I'll leave that up to you.

One last comment: I would include the `v.sku` column if it were me. That way, you can see if the price is for the specific `variant` or based on matching the `sku`.

Comment: The question is tagged with `sqlite`.  To my knowledege, `ISNULL()` should be changed to either `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()`.  See [sqlite functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull).

Comment: @CPerkins Thanks for catching that. I don't work with sqlite, so I missed the difference. I edited my answer accordingly. BTW: I think that `ISNULL() / IFNULL()` should be more efficient than `COALESCE()` when only checking one value rather than a series. Although a high-end optimizer (which I assume `[sqlite]` lacks) would convert the later into the former if there are only two parameters.